# How does myfonts keep track of page views for their webfonts?

Tags: javascript, server, webfonts

I'm wondering if anyone knows about how myfonts.com keeps track of page views for their webfonts that they offer. If you've ever tried to buy a font for the web from them - they have a pricing scale based on how many page views your site gets. The more page views the more the font costs. They also will give you a warning by email when you are getting close to your page view limit.

You can see here by this link that you get a JS tag to put in your site with the font you bought:
https://www.myfonts.com/info/webfonts/

If I wanted to make something on a small scale like this what do I need to learn and research? What sort of technology is involved in making this happen?

Answer (score 5):

Definitely a late answer :) Afaik, you have to embed their fonts either by CSS or JS (as you've already stated). Contained in those files the tracking algorithm is found.

Find below an excerpt of an email from MyFonts sent to a customer

> This @import rule used for the pageview tracking. Each time the page
>   using the webfonts is loaded, a single pageview is tracked. There are
>   two browser code options available when configuring your webfont kit
>   download: CSS or JS. With the CSS option, the pageviews are tracked by
>   an @import rule. Our JS kit will load the tracking async if you're
>   interested in that. For development you can comment out the @import
>   tracking, however, in production it must remain.

There is huge leap once you reach the limit of 500.000 page views. Be aware that if you bought three font faces for $60 they might charge you $1000 as soon as you cross the threshold. Often times you'll get to that point earlier than expected.

Comment: Better late than never! I'm just getting around to building this so the timing is serendipitous!. Thanks @Matt